# Nautilus hidden files issues (by window and by default) in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, hidden-files

I can't find how to configure some nautilus behaviour in Ubuntu 17.10, which I'm testing installed in an external drive.

If I have two nautilus windows, when I hide/unhide files (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>), it does it for all the open nautilus windows, not only in the one I'm working on. It didn't behave that way in previous versions, as it hid/unhid only the one currently in use.

Also, when I close Nautilus with "show hidden files" set, when I open it again it continues to be set, but I like it to always start not showing hidden files.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The Ctrl+h is a toggle, and is remembered across invocations of Nautilus.

Comment: Nothing to be done. Previously ctrl+h was a view binding, to set permanently one had to do that in  nautilus's preferences. Now ctrl+h changes the preference itself so it will be enabled for all nautilus windows unless disabled. So you'll need to disable after using by hitting ctrl+h again.

Comment: Ok, then this is Nautilus's new behaviour and can't be changed. Is there another file manager that works as Nautilus used to work? Nemo? Dolphin?

Comment: As far as nemo, the current 3.x would be the same, enabled or disabled. Not that hard to hit ctrl+h to toggle off..